# Python - update the same list and dict using the output of different functions, no code repetition

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a list and a dict, whose values I'm updating in different parts of the code using a structure like this:

```
final_list = []
final_dict = {}

for iter_1 in iterables_1:

    if condition_1:
        ret_1, ret_2 = my_func(...)
        if ret_1 is not None and ret_2 is not None:
            final_list.append(ret_1)
            final_dict[iter] = ret_2
    
    elif condition_2:
        for iter_2 in iterables_1:
            for iter_3 in iterables_3:
                ret_1, ret_2 = my_func(...)
                if ret_1 is not None and ret_2 is not None:
                    final_list.append(ret_1)
                    final_dict[iter] = ret_2
```

Now, everything works, but the lines:

```
ret_1, ret_2 = my_func(...)
if ret_1 is not None and ret_2 is not None:
    final_list.append(ret_1)
    final_dict[iter] = ret_2
```

are repeated (this is an oversimplification, the real code is much longer and this situation occurs more often).
In a case like this, how can I avoid this repetition?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention it, one option would be to move the repeated lines to my_func. However, unless I'm missing something, this would require having final_list and final_dict as both arguments and return value of my_func, so something like:

```
def my_func(final_list, final_dict, ...):
# calculate ret_1, ret_2
if ret_1 is not None and ret_2 is not None:
    final_list.append(ret_1)
    final_dict[iter] = ret_2

return final_list, final_dict

final_list = []
final_dict = {}

for iter_1 in iterables_1:

    if condition_1:
        final_list, final_dict = my_func(final_list, final_dict, ...)
    elif condition_2:
        for iter_2 in iterables_1:
            for iter_3 in iterables_3:
                final_list, final_dict = my_func(final_list, final_dict, ...)
```

But I'm not sure this is good practice either.

Comment: Put the repeated code into a discrete function. After all, that's one of the main reasons we use functions - i.e., reusable code

Comment: Well, I did think about it, but there was another issue in moving those lines to an external function. I edited the original question to - hopefully - make this point more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `if ret_1 is not None and ret_2 is not None:`  as your function doesn't return `None` but a list and a dict, which can be empty. But an empty list is not the same as `None`. So the `if` statement will never be false as `ret_1` and `ret_2` are never going to be `None`.

Try with  `if ret_1 and ret_2:`

Comment: Sorry, might have oversimplified the example. Anyway, in the first implementation example, my_func calculates ret_1 and ret_2 (which CAN be None) and returns them. The code checks if they're None and, if not, adds them to the list and dict. In the second implementation, I moved this check to my_func itself.

Comment: Please, post the actual code, then. As it is right now, `my_func` doesn't return `None`. In order to get help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).